# Datagridview filled with datasource = {}

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, tabcontrol

I'm having the most crazy issue ever I have one *tabcontrol*  where I add a tabpage then create a datagridview filling it with a query as datasource and make some visual changes on it and then make the same thing for another tabpage.

I run the code and somehow I get the data I want showing in the gridviews everything fine except the visual changes in the second one. I go debugging and end up finding out that the visual changes aren't happening because technically the query return the second datagridview gets as datasource is = {} so it has **no rows** to make visual changes on. but **the data is showing on the datagridview anyway**.
I tried changing the order of the datagridviews and it was the very same issue, so I think it's **something about the order** the code is but I don't understand what nor where exactly.

I'm working on Visual Studio 2012 in C#, accessing the data of a Access 2010 file. And here is the code in question:

```
        ///Tabela por calibrar
        DataTable tabelaEqui = null;
        tabelaEqui = calibracaoBL.planoCalibracaoAtualCalibradosServico(DateTime.Now.Year, servico);
        DataGridView gridPorCalibrar = new DataGridView();
        gridPorCalibrar.DataSource = tabelaEqui;

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(cbServico.Text + " - Por Calibrar");

        tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(gridPorCalibrar);
        gridPorCalibrar.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        gridPorCalibrar.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        gridPorCalibrar.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridPorCalibrar.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 5; j < gridPorCalibrar.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                string s = gridPorCalibrar.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                Boolean b = !s.Equals("");
                if (b)
                {
                    gridPorCalibrar.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
        mudarCabeçalho(gridPorCalibrar);


        ///Tabela Calibrados
        DataTable dt = null;
        dt = calibracaoBL.planoCalibracaoAnosAnterioresServico(DateTime.Now.Year, servico);
        DataGridView gridCalibrados = new DataGridView(); // here I got check and dt = {}
        gridCalibrados.DataSource = dt;

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(cbServico.Text + " - Calibrados");

        tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(gridCalibrados);
        gridCalibrados.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        gridCalibrados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        gridCalibrados.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridCalibrados.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 5; j < gridCalibrados.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                string s = gridCalibrados.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                Boolean b = !s.Equals("");
                if (b)
                {
                    gridCalibrados.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
        mudarCabeçalho(gridCalibrados);
```

Here is the first one:
[image]

Here is the second one:
[image]

UPDATE in response to @varocarbas :

I'm checking the datasource is blank in two points.
Point one:
dt = calibracaoBL.planoCalibracaoAnosAnterioresServico(DateTime.Now.Year, servico); // that method that runs a query returns {}. But the query itself is not the issue since it works just fine, it's working perfectly when I try it elsewhere.

Point two:
    DataTable dt = null;
    dt = calibracaoBL.planoCalibracaoAnosAnterioresServico(DateTime.Now.Year, servico);
    DataGridView gridCalibrados = new DataGridView(); // here I go check the dt variable and shows dt={}

The code goes into the *for (int i = 0; i < gridCalibrados.Rows.Count - 1; i++)* but since *gridCalibrados.Rows.Count* = 0 it skips the loop.

Here is the method *mudarCabeçalho*

```
    public void mudarCabeçalho(DataGridView grid)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i < grid.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            string[]  s = grid.Columns[i].HeaderText.Split('-');
            switch (s[1])
            {
                case "01":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Jan";
                    break;
                case "02":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Fev";
                    break;
                case "03":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Mar";
                    break;
                case "04":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Abr";
                    break;
                case "05":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Mai";
                    break;
                case "06":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Jum";
                    break;
                case "07":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Jul";
                    break;
                case "08":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Ago";
                    break;
                case "09":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Set";
                    break;
                case "10":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Out";
                    break;
                case "11":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Nov";
                    break;
                case "12":
                    grid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Dez";
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which "visual changes"?

Comment: @EmmadKareem changing the color of the cells with ** gridPorCalibrar.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Green; ** and the Text of the columns header with **mudarCabeçalho(gridPorCalibrar);**

Comment: This sounds certainly weird. We need more information to help you out. Please, post the code of `mudarCabeçalho`. Also clarify what is exactly happening while debugging: where are you checking that `DataSource` is blank? Before the loop? Is the code entering in the loop (but not in the condition), or not even in the loop?

Comment: This is a known issue with the datagridview on tabpages - I don't think there is any good work around, except running your coloring code when the tab control SelectedIndexChanged event fires

Comment: @DavidHall a known issue? Never heard about it! What is the exact problem? The DataSource gets blank when creating more than one DGV in different tabs? Can you please provide some references to this problem?

Comment: @varocarbas Here is a thread talking about it (lots of StackOverflow questions around it too) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b4f5079c-c8f1-4a2d-a476-8cbef1e0debb/datagridview-and-tabcontrol-bug?forum=winformsdatacontrols the problem is basically that the DGVs on non-visible tabs are not yet databound (or at least not completely) so the graphical half of the databinding is not ready to handle the changes. If you have previously viewed each tabpage then the problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidHall You are right. Actually I was doing a test now and have been able to replicate equivalent conditions to the OP ones! Certainly curious! I have used both, DataGridView and TabControl, a lot but, apparently, not to many times together! Always happy to learn something new (although a bug is rarely good news)! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting all the additional information (this is what you have to do always to get help quickly; if you don't show the whole problem, it might be difficult or impossible to find the solution). But, apparently, wasn't required: look at David Hall's comment; there is a bug with this specific combination of controls I personally wasn't aware of.

Comment: Yeah I was just checking it with a big facepalm to microsoft. A bit of a rant but...geez.... 8 years later the bug is still here.

Comment: @DavidHall this problem is only evident for persons who have dealt with this situation before (DataGridView + TabControl); I have lots of experience in both controls and haven't ever been in this situation. If you are debugging the code by your own and you see a so weird behaviour; first thing to do is a research and you would find references to this bug (neither evident nor overall-known at all). In this context, the first assumption is thinking that the OP did something wrong. Sorry for this clarification, but last 2 days have been kind of weird (people not understanding what seems evident).

Comment: @DavidHall On the other hand, knowing that the DataTable is a kind of datasource with which the DataGridView deals really well; and that a multi-property Class is not so well dealt with (distinction "columns/rows"), is something which you should know in case of using DataGridView regularly (-> evident); and I have answered a question right now of a person not having such an idea clear enough. I insist sorry for this late-replying and I am not insinuating that you belong to the under-understanding people I am referring, but have been too long days (dealing with this people is really tiring) :)